# Python on Heroku. Logging options?

Tags: python, logging, heroku, flask

I am using Flask on Heroku right now and I want to be able to log errors to a file (via FileHandler).

I don't think that's officially supported by heroku.

On heroku's logging page there's some mentioning of syslogs and drains, which seem pretty complicated to set up.

I want something quick and easy. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 7):

Anything your app writes to `stdout` will end up in Heroku's consolidated log for your application, according to their [docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-faq#what-happens-to-data-written-to-standard-out), which you can then access with `heroku log` and the other tools. That's probably the quickest/easiest way to get logs from your app to a place you can look at them.

Answer (score 2):

Follow on [heroku logging](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging)

To view your logs we have:

1. logs command retrives 100 log lines by default.

> heroku logs

2. show maximum 1500 lines, --num(or -n) option.

> heroku logs -n 200

3. Show logs in real time

> heroku logs --tail

4. If you have many apps on heroku

> heroku logs --app your_app_name

5. You can use this addons [papertrail](https://addons.heroku.com/papertrail). 
   Log volume per day(10mb),  search back of logs (2 days), archive duration (7days)

Answer (score 0):

If you want your own file I would try this:

```
print('Hello', 'World', 2+3, file=open('file.txt', 'w'))
```

You can do what Minh Nguyen said or you can add the [paper trails](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/papertrail) dyno which can be configured to send updates by email or slack.